# Convert DataFrame from numeric to string with mapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Convert Dataframe from string to numeric (as IDs) with mapping so that I can map numeric values back to string after my Machine Learning job (which requires numeric values for training)

I have 2 columns in my data frame:-

1. `Repository Name`(String that is needed to be converted)
2. `Number of Stars`(Numeric value, hence nothing to be done)

I want to convert string as IDs and need to map these to use it in future.

Note: My strings are words like `freecodecamp` and not integer values in strings.

Comment: I would suggest using one hot encoding if your strings are from countable or you can try replacing string with corresponding ascii values

Comment: Since my work is based on Machine Learning job, it would lead to a lot of overhead in training.

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/how-to-convert-string-to-number-and-number-to-string-efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_metadata(df, key, val):
    #create a new column with index 
    df['index'] = df.index
    if key == "Repository Name":
        return {str(row[key]): row[val] for _, row in df.iterrows()}
    else:
        return {row[key]: row[val] for _, row in df.iterrows()}

emb2idx = get_metadata(dataframe, "index", "Repository Name")
```

You will get a dictionary of index(ID) and your string(Repository Name) to map in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these conversions in python using `ord()`. For example, to convert `name` to the ASCII character codes, you could use the following loop.

```
name = "John"
nameascii = []

for c in name:
    nameascii.append(ord(c))

print(nameascii)
```

To convert back to a char, use `char()`.

However, if your model was built using tensor-flow the `tf.string_to_number` function is probably better(and faster) because the conversions can be done concurrently whereas the above loop will run sequentially.